# Cannot compile code with Magick++ (library issue)

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin, imagemagick, magick++

I'm currently trying to get a simple c++ code to compile with the Magick++ API. The actual code I'm comipling is dirt simple. Just a "hello world" with #include Magick++.h at the top.

The problem is that the compiler cant seem to find -lMagick++. See the error below

ImageMagick was installed from binaries in cygwin over windows 7. I did the following configuration after install

```
export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/ImageMagick-6.8.8"
export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:}$MAGICK_HOME/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/pkgconfig"
```

CPP file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    cout<<"Hello Magick++"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ `Magick++-config --cppflags` -o hello hello_world.cpp \ `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`
```

Which spits back:

```
g++:  -lMagick++: No such file or directory 
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-fopenmp" is valid for D but not for C++
hello_world.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
hello_world.cpp:7: error: `InitializeMagick' undeclared (first use this function)
hello_world.cpp:7: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
```

Comment: Please show the output of `Magick++-config --cppflags` and `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`

Comment: Where did the `-fopenmp` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `-fopenmp` from the `--cppflags`. It gets added by the `Magick(Core|Wand|++)-config` because your compiler supports the feature (at time of autoconfig), but doesn't mean (or check) that OpenMP is available for the system. I get this all the time when using LLVM-clang, and forget to install the [OpenMP plugin](http://openmp.llvm.org)

You can fix this be reconfiguring + recompiling the ImageMagick with `--disable-openmp`.

Or perhaps installing [OpenMP](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) for gcc.

Or just strip out the tag

```
g++ -o hello \
    `Magick++-config --cppflags | sed 's/-fopenmp//g'` \
    `Magick++-config --libs | sed 's/-fopenmp//g'` \
    hello_world.cpp
```

Personally -- I would recommend just stripping out the tag until your more comfortable with compiling + linking, and then see about installing the openmp plugin/feature.